# Проблема с JSON

Tags: json, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть обработчик на JS:

```
function auth() {
        var user = {
            login: $("#login").val(),
            password:$("#password").val(),
        }

        $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-block">Подождите...</div>');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/file.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").empty();
                if (data.status == 'error') $('#result').html('<div class = "alert alert-error">'+data.msg+'</div>');
                if (data.status == 'ok') $('#result').html(data.msg);
                //$('#result').html(data.msg);
            },
        });
    }
```

сервер:

```
$user = json_decode($user,true);
if (!empty($user['login']) && !empty($user['password'])) {
    $data = array('status'=>'','msg'=>'ок, данные пришли');
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    $data = array('status'=>'error','msg'=>'неправильно ввели пароль');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Проблема в том, что массив $user не дошёл вроде до сервера, помогите найти ошибку

Comment: А вас не смущает тот факт, что в ``JS``'е вы не отправляете ``user``, а в PHP не принимаете (или не показываете, или.. ну не ``register_globals`` же?)

Comment: Да, да. Добавьте в ajax параметр **data**.

    $.ajax({
            url: '/file.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {user: передаваемый_параметр},
            success: function (data) {
                $("#result").empty();
                if (data.status == 'error') $('#result').html('<div class = "alert alert-error">'+data.msg+'</div>');
                if (data.status == 'ok') $('#result').html(data.msg);
                //$('#result').html(data.msg);
            },
        });

Comment: Как в пхп принять переданный массив

Comment: К слову, для того, чтобы знать, что ушло, но недошло, а что и не уходило, есть всякие Developer Tools в каждом нормальном браузере. Пользуйтесь ими.

Comment: **$_POST['user']** - будет содержать передаваемые данные

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/file.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: user,
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
```

Comment: И еще, на сервере: `$user = $_POST['user']; $user = json_decode($user,true);
if (!empty($user['login']) && !empty($user['password'])) {`